# What is the most efficient way to change a SAS data set label?

Tags: sas

Actually, this question is for updating all data set attributes.

Using a DATA STEP, updating the label can accomplished this way:

```
Data HAVE (Label="Updated or New label");
 Set HAVE;
Run;
```

This is fine if there are only a few thousand observations, but not if there are a 100 million.

Answer (score 3):

Using [PROC DATASETS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0xdkenol7pi1cn14p0iq38shax4.htm) is the most efficient way to update SAS data set attributes. This PROC also has other uses that are very efficient.

To update a data set label use the [MODIFY](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0mfav25learpan1lerk79jsp30n.htm) statement within PROC DATASETS:

```
Proc Datasets LIB=WORK;
 Modify HAVE (Label="A new or updated label");
 Run;
Quit;
```

Here are some good SAS papers about using PROC DATASETS:
[The Swiss Army Knife of SAS Procedures - Michael A. Raithel](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/274-2011.pdf)
[Professional SAS Programming Shortcuts - SAS Publishing](http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/59353.pdf)
[SAS Tip sheet - DATASETS](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/Tipsheet_DATASETS.pdf)